# How can I create a DB table field called SECTION in MS Access?

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, ado

If I dispatch this SQL statement by TADOCommand.execute:

```
CREATE TABLE Spice ( MODEL TEXT NOT NULL, PART TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, SECTION TEXT NOT NULL, FOOTPRINT TEXT NOT NULL, NODELIST TEXT NOT NULL );
```

It says:

```
Syntax error in field definition
```

But if I rename SECTION to SECTION2 it works. I tried to quote it "SECTION" and 'SECTION' but it appeared in the name. Should I define the quotation mark or escape char somehow?
Whan I use MS Access, I could create a field called SECTION with it!

Comment: Have you tried `[SECTION]`?

Comment: @kobik Thanks kobik. It works fine. If you create an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following works fine for me:

```
  AdoCommand1.CommandText :=
  'CREATE TABLE Spice ( MODEL TEXT NOT NULL, PART TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, [SECTION] TEXT NOT NULL, FOOTPRINT TEXT NOT NULL, NODELIST TEXT NOT NULL );';
  AdoCommand1.Execute;
```

Note the square brackets around SECTION, which avoids collisions between SQL keywords and object names in most circumstances.

Answer (score -2):

Section is a reserve word in SQL so you shouldn't use it to name an object. For a complete list of words, see the link below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Comment: But in this case how could MS Access create a field called SECTION?

Comment: You can look at this explanation for MS ACCESS. If you use a reserve word for a field name, Access will only warn you that you may run into issues. It's possible your tool doesn't know how to handle the warning or this is one of those issues. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe